# DropDownList has a invalid SelectedValue Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing this website for a school project, and when I run this website I have a GridView where I select one registry, then it opens the FormView with all the details about the selected registry

[Image of the website working](http://prntscr.com/4qdgxa)

Now, when I hit that Edit on the FormView it gives me the following error:
**'ddl_SelectMae' has a invalid SelectedValue  because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value**

I know that, this error appears because the value on field "Mãe" is null, but I saw the database and that value can be null. (Same error applies to the "Pai" and "Comprador" field)

Here the part of the code where error happens, I can put all the code if needed

```
<asp:FormView ID="fv_Alteracoes" runat="server" DataKeyNames="idCao" DataSourceID="SqlDS_InsEdiDel">
       <EditItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mãe:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dll_SelectMae" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDS_ListarMae" DataTextField="idCao" DataValueField="idCao"
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Mae") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDS_ListarMae" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [idCao], [Nome] FROM [tbl_Cao] WHERE ([Sexo] = 'F')">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
               </table>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
       </EditItemTemplate>
```

---

If I do the same but with a registry with all the details filled the website works 100% as I want

[Image of website working perfectly](http://prntscr.com/4qdhy6)

Can someone help me how to stop that error and keep the DropDownList to edit the fields?

***PS: Sorry about my English but I am Portuguese, thank you for help***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Data Source so that null can be allowed as :

```
SELECT [idCao], [Nome] FROM [tbl_Cao] WHERE ([Sexo] = 'F')
union 
Select null,'None'
```